# Remote access a dynamic ip address on a 3g dongle?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, ssh, 3g

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to figure out if it's possible to have a remote access using ssh keys on a 3g dongle?
Is there any possible way?
Maybe using a 3g wireless router?
How to set-up?
Can I access Dynamic IP address?
Sorry got a lot of questions this is for my project.
I hope you guys can help or sort it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible to have remote access using a 3g dongle. To get started, open up the terminal on the machine you want to remotely access and type `ifconfig` and note the ip address under the pppoe section. This will be the ip address of your machine on the internet. Then you can just `ssh user@ip_address` from your other machine and you're good to go.

However there are some problems with this method.

1. Your ip address might change every time you reconnect the dongle since it uses dhcp to get its ip address from its server. So you might have to perform `ifconfig` every time which defeats the entire point of remote access.
2. Since your dongle probably doesn't use NAT, all your open ports are exposed to the internet which could be potentially dangerous. I'd suggest you use iptables or some other firewall to close up the ports which are not required.

Comment: About point 1, you can configure the remote machine to send emails periodically with the IP in use. Here is such script: https://askubuntu.com/a/907784/566421