# Use Outgoing SSH to receive incoming SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-access

My ISP does not allow me to have a static IP address. As such I am unable to remotely SSH in my home machine. Is there a way I could SSH from my home machine to a server and SSH into the server from my remote laptop and bridge the two connections?

Cheers!

Comment: There's quite a nice discussion of *reverse tunneling* at [How does reverse SSH tunneling work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just copy/paste (slightly modified) part of **@b_laoshi**'s answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/903082/566421):

> In this case, you can configure your ssh tunnel from ComputerA ->
>   ComputerB such it can **tunnel reverse connections** as well.
>
> When establishing the ssh connection ComputerA -> ComputerB, do so
>   with the `-R` option in the following manner:
>
> ```
> ssh ComputerBUser@ComputerB -R 2222:localhost:22
> ```
>
> where `ComputerBUser` is the username for the account on ComputerB
>   being authenticated and `2222` is a free port on ComputerB. We'll use
>   this port to **reverse-tunnel** back to ComputerA from ComputerB.
>
> Now **from ComputerB**, you can issue the scp command in the following
>   manner to copy files from ComputerB -> ComputerA where `ComputerAUser`
>   is your username on ComputerA:
>
> ```
> scp -P 2222 /path/to/file/on/ComputerB ComputerAUser@localhost:/path/to/drop/file/on/computerA
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> ssh -p 2222 ComputerAUser@localhost
> ```
>
> What's happening here?
>
> It looks like we are simply telling ComputerB to send the file back to
>   itself because we're passing `localhost` instead of ComputerA. We are
>   indeed telling scp to pass the file back to ComputerB, but to port
>   2222. All connections to port 2222 on ComputerB get forwarded to port 22 (default ssh port) on ComputerA.
>
> Thus, by tunneling backwards over the existing ssh connection, it
>   doesn't matter that ComputerA is behind an NAT firewall.

**EDIT:**
To allow to establish a SSH tunnel without the need for an active terminal window, one can add the `-N` parameter (before the `-R`) (as pointed out in the link provided by @steeldriver). Moreover, if one wants to automatically setup a permanent background ssh connection, Erik Torgesta's [great article](https://erik.torgesta.com/tag/ssh-upstart/) provides you with all the necessary steps.

Related topics:

- [How do I access the SSH client side from the SSH server side?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031904/566421)
- [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005337/566421)

Comment: You sir, have made my day. Thanks to @b_laoshi and to the awesome people who thought of this epic corner case.
My nerdom has been rewarded.

Comment: Another small question: is there a way I can run the reverse tunnel `ssh user@host -R 2222:localhost:22` as a background process and still be able to ssh in computer A from computer B? I would like to setup the connection from boot automatically

Comment: @PhilippeHebert, I never tried this. Could you try it, and [elaborate](https://askubuntu.com/posts/907755/edit) the answer if you succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way I have set up on my own server.

I have my server check its external ip address every 15 minutes (times between checks are customisable by cron) 
It then compares this with its most recent ip address and if it has changed, it emails me the new ip address.

I'm on my phone at the minute but can send the setup through if you like, it's really quite simple and pretty reliable except for the odd spurious email when the server can't reach the ip checker.

Update - here's the script. You obviously need a functioning email account running, personally I have mine set up to send from a dedicated gmail account using [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/postfix_relaying_through_another_mailserver)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
IPADDRESS=$(curl https://wtfismyip.com/text)
if [ "$IPADDRESS" != "$(cat /home/will/scripts/.current_ip)" ]
then
    dt=$(date)
    echo "Your new IP address as of ${dt} is ${IPADDRESS} \r \r FTB" | mail -s "IP address change" emailforupdates@email.com
    echo "$IPADDRESS" >| /home/will/scripts/.current_ip
    echo "$dt $IPADDRESS" >> /home/will/scripts/.iphistory
fi
```

I'd start off by `touch .current_ip && touch .iphistory` in the directory where you're going to store the files. It has the added advantage of keeping a record of IP changes, though I haven't found much use for it to be honest.

Set the script up to run as a cron job as often as you like. It's not very  resource intensive.

Comment: Yes, Will, it would be nice if you provide more details.

Comment: @SpasSpasov I've updated my answer with my script. There may be a more elegant way to do it but it works.

Comment: It is nice but it doesn't work in my case as my ISP does not provide me with a static IP that I can access. My guess is that the IP I am given is the IP of a switch/router somewhere in their systems and I have an internal IP I cannot get

Comment: @PhilippeHebert that's the reason for my script. I don't have a static ip either. The script regularly checks your ip and emails you if it has changed. It's worked well for me for 2 years (though I did have to change the service I used to check my ip as the old one kept failing to deliver a response). Online ip address checkers return your *public* ip, which is the one you'll need to access your system from outside your own network.

Comment: Interesting, it gives back the IPv6 address. Welp, I'd use it but my VPN provider doesn't support IPv6 :/