# Script that send Public/Global IP On restart

Tags: networking, server, ssh, email

I own a server at my Parents house and recently there has been a lot of power cuts and when our Router comes back online it changes its Public/Global IP address which makes me unable to connect to it (SSH, FTP, HTTP) ,is there any way that I could make a script that when the power goes out on my server and it reboots it send an email with my Global/Public IP to me.

Comment: Hi, Joiie, I think [**this is the right answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/907784/566421) for your question. I can create step by step 'manual', but later today :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using sendmail.
install

```
sudo apt install -y postfix
```

choose `internet side` and enter your server's hostname

Write a script e.g. in `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/sendIPmail`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. gets the primary IP
#from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851186/7111561
IP=$( ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}' )


# 2. send it using sendmail
#from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390926/7111561

#--- adjust those ---
recipients="your.mail@address,another@mail.address"
subject="some subject"
from="info@your.server"
#--------------------

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" <<EOF
subject:$subject
from:$from

New IP is $IP
EOF

exit 0
```

make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sendIPmail
```

and call it on every reboot
run

```
sudo crontab -e
```

(select your editor e.g. 2 for nano)
Add the line

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/sendIPmail
```

This does not require any external webpages or complex scripts/setups and uses only packages from the official Ubuntu repos. 


**NOTE: Alternatively you really should consider using a static IP address for a server!**

Answer (score 1):

use my script.

1. Clone the script from my github repo:

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/sendExternalIPAddress.git`

2. then move the `sendexternalip.bash` file from the directory `sendExternalIPAddress` to `/usr/lib` - use the following command to do so.

`sudo cp sendExternalIPAddress/sendexternalip.bash /usr/lib`

3. now make the script executable:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/sendexternalip.bash`

4. for the first time, to install all the necessary packages and dependencies: 
   `sudo /usr/lib/sendexternalip.bash`
5. now to make the script run automatically on startup run the following command:

`sudo printf "start on startup\ntask\nexec /us/lib/sendexternalip.bash\n" > ~/.config/upstart/sendexternalip.conf`

This will make your Linux box email it's current external IP address to the email address specified in the script.

N.B. The script - by default - sends the External IP address to the email address "receiver@grr.la", however, you can change the `customReceiverEmail` variable on line 9 of the script to any `@grr.la` address of you choosing and the IP address will be sent to that address instead.

Comment: I think one of the issues here is if they don't have GoeillaMail - the entire thing seems to rely on that based on your answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer and fixed a bit. would you be so kind as to go through the answer - from the top - once more and up-vote the reply when it works .. lol .. btw, really sorry for the hassle - but the improved answer will work. Also gorilla mail is a free and anonymous messaging service. google it.  no sign up or subscription is needed. in your case you just insert the email address "receiver@grr.la" in the box at the homepage and voila, you can see all the emails that are sent to that account. these are disposable email addresses.