# Access remote multiple servers behind NAT

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote-access, teamviewer

I have a situation where our Ubuntu servers were deployed across multiple remote locations. These servers were behind a carrier grade NAT and also an internal NAT. Now from a central location I want to access it any time I want, but I am also behind a NAT similar to those servers.

[image]

When those servers are online I want to access it (through SSH or SSH tunnel). I know I can't access like servers that have a public IP, but maybe somehow I can access it through TeamViewer's working principle. For this method if I need another public server I can manage it in Google Compute Engine.

Comment: I have full control over servers but might not be able to do networking on clients premises.May be some VPN Stuff..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we have access to a server with public IP address, then we can use it as a gateway. We could achieve this via Reverse SSH Port Forwarding connections. Let’s say we have three instances:

- **Public Server**: Here we have an operational SSH server and public IP address (and/or domain name). We are able to connect to this server with public-private key pair, which is not passphrase protected ([setup reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986179/permission-denied-when-trying-to-run-a-script-that-uses-sshpass/986245#986245)).
- **Private Server**: Here we have an operational SSH server. It is behind a Firewall (NAT, ISP, etc.) and doesn't have a public IP address, but we are able to establish a SSH connection from it to the Public Server, so here we have also SSH client.
- **Client Machine**: Here we (need to) have only SSH client. We are able to establish a SSH connection to the Public Server. **We want to establish a SSH connection from this instance to the Private Server.**

---

## The principal level

At principal level we could apply at least two scenarios.

**Scenario 1.** Where we don’t want to open an additional ports in the Public Server’s Firewall:

1. Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Private Server to the Public Server.
2. Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Client Machine to the Public Server.
3. Connect to the Private Server from the Client Machine via the forwarded port (through itself).

**Scenario 2.** Where we are inclined to open an additional port in the Public Server’s Firewall:

1. Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Private Server to the Public Server.
2. Connect to the Private Server from the Client Machine through the Public Server.

The main advantage of the Scenario 1 is that we don’t need to think how secure is our Private Server. The main advantage of the Scenario 2 is that we ommit one step, but in this case we should think about the security of the Private Server, because it becomes public accessible through the forwarded port. In addition, these scenarios could be applied to different port and services, not only SSH, for example to HTTP.

---

## How to apply Scenario 1 within Ubuntu

**Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Private Server to the Public Server**

We could do that by the command:

```
ssh user-of-the-public-server@public-server -p 22 -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 -i ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa
```

- `-p 22` provides the SSH port of the Public Server (it is not mandatory).
- `-i ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa` provides the authentication key file.
- `-R 2222:127.0.0.1:22` means that port `2222` on the (remote) Public Server will be forwarded to the SSH port of the (local) Private Server that, in this case, is `22`.

We can push this connection into the background by adding the options `-fTN` (of the OpenSSH Client – [reference](https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/3/what-is-reverse-ssh-port-forwarding)). We could use also the tool `autossh` to be sure the connection will be kept alive for a long period of time ([reference](https://erik.torgesta.com/tag/ssh-upstart/)):

```
autossh user-of-the-public-server@public-server -p 22 -fTN -R 2222:127.0.0.1:22 -i ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa
```

We can simplify the above command by implementation of the following lines in our `~/.ssh/config` file:

```bsh
Host public-server-reverse
    HostName 100.100.100.100
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa
    User user-of-the-public-server
    Port 22
    RemoteForward 2222 localhost:22
```

- 100.100.100.100 is the IP address or the domain name of the Public Server

In this case the above command will become:

```bsh
autossh public-server-reverse -fTN
```

We can easily automate this task on system reboot by the next Cron job (or we could [create service](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) that should be the better approach):

```bsh
@reboot sleep 45 && autossh public-server-reverse -fTN
```

Once this connection is established we can connect to the Private Server from the Public Server, through the reverse tunnel, by the command:

```bsh
ssh user-of-the-private-server@localhost -p 2222    # provide an additional authentication data (for the Private Server) if it is needed…
```

**Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Client Machine to the Public Server**

We could do that by the command:

```bsh
ssh user-of-the-public-server@public-server -p 22 -fTN -L 1111:127.0.0.1:2222 -i ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa
```

- `-L 1111:127.0.0.1:2222`  means that port `1111` on the (local) Client Machine will be forwarded to the (remote) Public Server’s port `2222` (that is forwarded to the SSH port of the Private Server). Note we could use `-L 2222:127.0.0.1:2222`.
- `-fTN` these options will push the connection into the background as it is described above.
- We can implement also `autossh` and `~/.ssh/config` file, with directive  `RemoteForward` or `LocalForward`.

**Connect to the Private Server from the Client Machine through itself**

Once the above two steps are implemented, we can connect from the Client Machine to the Public Server by the command:

```bsh
ssh user-of-the-private-server@localhost -p 1111    # provide an additional authentication data (for the Private Server) if it is needed…
```

---

## How to apply Scenario 2 within Ubuntu

**Establish SSH connection with Port Forwarding from the Private Server to the Public Server**

This step is identical as the first one from the Scenario 1, but few additional things should be done.

Open the forwarded port `2222` on the Public Server’s Firewall - this is out of the scope of this answer.

Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the Public Server and add the next directive, that will allow to open our SSH tunnel to public (don't forget to restart the server: `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`):

```bsh
GatewayPorts yes
```

Make our SSH tunnel open to public. This step is well described within the question: ([How to make ssh tunnel open to public?](https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public)). According to the answers there we could add the `-g` option to the commands that make a connection between the Private and the Public servers:

```bsh
autossh public-server-reverse -gfTN
```

```bsh
@reboot sleep 45 && autossh public-server-reverse -gfTN
```

Or, alternatively, instead that we could modify the `~/.ssh/config` file in this way:

```bsh
Host public-server-reverse
    HostName 100.100.100.100  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pass-less/id_rsa
    User user-of-the-public-server
    Port 22
    RemoteForward \*:2222 localhost:22
```

- 100.100.100.100  is the IP address or the domain name of the Public Server

Finally we should `killall autossh` and establish the connection again.

**Connect to the Private Server from the Client Machine through the Public Server**

Once the above step is performed, we can achieve our goal by the command:

```bsh
ssh user-of-the-private-server@public-server -p 2222    # provide an additional authentication data (for the Private Server) if it is needed… forward some ports, etc.
```

---

## Update

In case the *Public* Server and the *Private* Server are in the same LAN you could use either of the options [**ProxyCommand**](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/) or [**ProxyJump**](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host). The option **ProxyJump** is available at OpenSSH 7.4+, with this option you could easily pass through [multiple gateways](https://wiki.bnl.gov/astro/index.php/ProxyCommand). Here is few examples:

```bsh
ssh -J PublicServer PrivateServer
ssh -J user1@PublicServer:port1 user2@PrivateServer -p port2
ssh -J user1@PublicServer:port1,user2@IntermediateServer:port2 user3@PrivateServer -p port3
```

Or if you would prefer to use `~/.ssh/config` entry:

```bsh
Host PublicServer
        HostName 100.100.100.100
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/public_server_id_rsa
        User User1
        Port 10222

Host PrivateServer
        HostName 172.16.1.100
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_server_id_rsa
        User User2
        Port 22
        ProxyJump PublicServer
```

- Note, the both SSH keys are stored at the Client Machine.
- 100.100.100.100 is the IP address or the domain name of the Public Server. 172.16.1.0/24 is the LAN where the Private Server is accessible by the Public Server. And 172.16.1.100 is the LAN IP address of the Private Server.

Then, in order to connect to the Private server, just use:

```bsh
ssh PrivateServer
```