# How do I securely set up a public-facing remote access server on my home machine?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, lubuntu, remote-desktop

I want to access my home computer from my laptop over the internet.
Both run Lubuntu.

I'm sure this is a talked-to-death topic, but most guides I find seem to be incomplete and somewhat careless from the security perspective. Setting up a vulnerable public-facing remote access service on my main machine would be a massive disaster for me. The drive contains lots of confidential and otherwise sensitive information.

*Can you provide a complete guide (or link to it) with all the key security considerations included?*

(ie are the default openssh settings good enough? What about xrdp? What needs to be done?)

Comment: If your router supports VPN, use it with strong passwords and you'll be fine. I think this question is too broad and there are a lot of similar questions around here. Did you do any research before asking volunteers to provide you with a *complete guide*?

Comment: @RoVo This is an example of the bad advice I'm trying to navigate around. Routers are often the most vulnerable entry point with old/abandoned firmware and multiple exploits available. I'm not asking volunteers to write me a book, I'm asking for the title of a good one. And this is because most of my searches end up with quick blogposts or stackexchange answers of a guy that short of knows enough to get openssh running, but he doesn't understand what he's really doing.  So yes, I did my research, and I'd like for someone knowledgeable to help me find a concise guide to do remote access safely.

Comment: If your router is the vulnerable entry point and does not receive updates anymore, you should consider getting a different brand which provides updates.

Comment: Maybe something like Teamviewer would suit your needs: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-install-TeamViewer-on-Ubuntu/ta-p/45

Comment: Probably you will find this topic useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1005337/566421 There: 1) One VPS is engaged to be mediator between the home server and the client computer; 2) The home server is setup to establish a connection with port forwarding to the VPS; 3) From the client computer you need to: 3.1) establish ssh connection with port forwarding to the VPS; 3.2) establish ssh connection (through the already created ssh tunnel) to the home server and here you can forward some additional ports (VNC or/and RDP); 4) at this point you can connect to these forwarded ports (VNC or/and RDP)...

Comment: You can use different ssh keys for each ssh connection and can protect the key of the home server with pass phrase...

Comment: @pa4080 Thank you for your useful answer.

Comment: Also consider using fail2ban