# Ssh proxy server

Tags: ssh, socks5

Hi I have Ubuntu server.

I want to install a ssh proxy server like below.

https://cyberssh.com/ssh/region/europe

I want use eproxy APK.

- Port 443
- Socks5
- Local port 1080
- Udp port 7300

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a UDP port for a SOCKS5 proxy. What's the UDP port 7300 used for?

Comment: I think also this Q&A will be interesting for you [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005337/566421).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005337/access-remote-multiple-servers-behind-nat)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly I think you're describing a SOCKS proxy. Those are very straightforward on Ubuntu.

### Secure the server (optional but recommended)

I would recommend hardening the server a couple ways

1. Set a strong password on the server (ideally [use a key](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/) and disable passwords)
2. Assuming your username on the server is "proserver1", add the line `AllowUsers proserver1` to the end of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that only you can log in

### Install the SSH server application on your server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

### Configure ssh to use port 443

If you want to use port 443 you'll need to edit the configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Find the line that reads

```
# Port 22
```

and change it to

```
Port 443
```

(note that I removed the number symbol).

### Open port 443 to the internet

The next part requires knowledge of your setup so I can't provide specific help... You need to allow access to the server port 443 from the internet. The way you do that will depend on how the server is hosted.

For example if you are running the server on your home network, you'll need to configure your router to pass port 443 of the server to the internet.

You may need to contact your hosting service about port forwarding.

### Determine your public IP (optional if you have a domain service)

You'll need the public IP address or domain for your server. On the server you can run the following to get the public IP:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

### Establish the proxy

Eproxy will need the following

- HOST/IP: use the IP from the previous step
- Port: 443
- SOCKS5: checked
- Local Port: 1080

Since this is the Ubuntu stack exchange I'll also include the ssh commands for an Ubuntu client:

```
ssh -D 1080 -p 443 proserver1@the.ip.address
```