# How do I access the SSH client side from the SSH server side?

Tags: ssh

Normally there is an SSH client that connects to an SSH server. The client then places commands that are executed on the server. Now, is there a way to do it the other way around? So that the client connects to the server, but the server also connects to the client and is able to execute commands on the client. Is that possible?

The reason I am looking for this is that I have two servers (A and B) in two different networks, both networks connected to the Internet. Server A can be accessed through port forwarding, but server B cannot. Since server A does all the work I'd like server B to connect to server A and just do whatever server A wants it to do.

Are reverse connections like this possible? Or maybe bidirectional SSH connections?

**EDIT**:

As an example I'd like to do the following. Being on server A and knowing that server B is SSH-connected to me, I'd like to connect to connect to server B and place a command like

```
echo "This is test content." > /home/myuser/mytestfile`
```

After that I'd like to find a file

```
/home/myuser/mytestfile
```

in server B.

Comment: Could you add a bit more details on what kind of commands you want to run? Should it be an interactive login or some automated process? In principle you should be able to do everything using ssh (reverse) port forwarding (options `-L` and `-R` for ssh)

Comment: @SebastianStark Edited the posting.

Comment: @SebastianStark Do you have an example syntax for `-L` and `-R`?

Comment: Just to make sure: can you ssh from server A to B? Or only from B to A?

Comment: Also these topics could be interesting: [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006245/566421) and [Making a .sh script to check if SSH connection exists and if not then connect](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028377/566421)

Comment: I don't understand. If you are on serverA and want to run a command on serverB, then you can do `ssh serverB echo "This is test content." > /home/myuser/mytestfile`. The `mytesfile` will be created on serverA but the command will be run on serverB. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @SebastianStark The gateway router of the network of server A allows port forwarding. The gateway router of the network of server B does not. Hence, I cannot make server B accessible from the Internet over a designated port. Hence, out of the Internet only server A can be reached, not server B. To server A, server B is just a client.

Comment: @terdon The command is triggered by server A, but executed on server B, hence the resulting file will be located on server B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031904/access-connecting-ssh-client/1032080#comment1678215_1031904) you can use the following command to execute *something* on the remote server through SSH and save (redirect) the output to the local instance:

```
UserA@HostA:~$  ssh UserB@HostB ls ~ > /home/UserA/ls-of-home-UserB.txt
```

Also you can use the following command to execute *something* on the local instance and pipe the output to the remote server and save it by the command `tee`:

```
UserA@HostA:~$  ls ~ | ssh UserB@HostB tee /home/UserB/ls-of-home-UserA.txt
```

---

I'm [agree with](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031904/access-connecting-ssh-client/1032080#comment1678186_1031904) [@Sebastian Stark](https://askubuntu.com/users/804762/sebastian-stark) you are probably asking how to create revers tunnel with SSH port forwarding. The SSH connection allows to bind  port on the **remote** server **to** port on the **local** by using the option **`-R`**. And vice versa you can bind **local** port **to** **remote** port by **`-L`**.

In your case should be applied the first scenario by using the option `-R`:

```
UserA@HostA:~$  ssh UserB@HostB -R 2222:localhost:22
```

This command will establish connection from `HostA` to `HostB` as usual and will bind port `2222` on `HostB` to port `22` on the loopback interface on `HostA`. That means when you request *something* on port `2222` on `HostB` the request will be handled by the service that listen on port `22` on `HostA`, usually this is the SSH server. At this point you could be able to use some of the following commands to connect back from `HostB` to `HostA`:

```
UserB@HostB:~$  ssh UserA@HostB -p 2222
UserB@HostB:~$  ssh UserA@localhost -p 2222
```

Or you can use the above commands, for example:

```
UserB@HostB:~$  ls ~ | ssh UserA@localhost -p 2222 tee /home/UserA/ls-of-home-UserB.txt
```

**Note you should have installed SSH server on `HostA`!**

---

One interesting usage is that you can bind remote port on `HostB` to port on other instance in the local network of `HostA`:

```
UserA@HostA:~$  ssh UserB@HostB -fTN -R 3389:192.168.100.115:3389
```

Where `192.168.100.115` is the IP address on any Windows computer in the LAN of `HostA`, let's call it `HostC`. The options `-fTN` will push the ssh connection into the background and you will have just a tunnel from `HostB:3389` through `HostA` to `HostC:3389`.

---

I'm using this by combination with `autossh` to keep the connection alive. For example I have the next line in my `crontab`:

```bsh
@reboot sleep 15 && autossh remote-server-with-public-ip -fTN
```

Where `remote-server-with-public-ip` is a *Host* defined in my `~/.ssh/config` file on `HostA`:

```bsh
Host remote-server-with-public-ip
    HostName hostB
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/hostB/id_rsa
    User userB
    Port 22
    RemoteForward 2223 127.0.0.1:22
    RemoteForward 8080 127.0.0.1:80
    RemoteForward 6900 127.0.0.1:5900
    RemoteForward 3389 192.168.100.115:3389
```

The ports `2223`, `6900`, `3389` on `HostB` are not public and I can access them only through another SSH connection - for example from `HostD` that is somewhere on Internet. But to access `8080` I'm using Apache with reverse proxy on `HostB` :-) and the virtual host's configuration file looks as this:

```bsh
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

    ServerName forward.example.com
    # Other configuration directives

    SSLEngine on
    # SSL certificate files

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass "/"  "http://localhost:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://localhost:8080/"

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

- The Apache's modules `proxy` and `proxy_http` are required.

---

Further reading:

- [Access remote multiple servers behind NAT](https://askubuntu.com/q/1005337/566421)
- [Making a .sh script to check if SSH connection exists and if not then connect](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028338/566421)
- [Use Outgoing SSH to receive incoming SSH](https://askubuntu.com/q/907753/566421)

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer. Quite a few options. And I must admit, that I was quite surprised about the possibility to bind another local host to the remote host using `-fTN`. Although, killing that connection is a bit tricky. I solved it a bit dirty using `sudo pkill ssh`. Apparently there is an `ssh -S` option, but I coudn't get it to work. It asks for some socket I don't know where to get from. As for me, the answer to my matter is the `ssh -R`, binding a port on the remote host (2222) to myself (22).